# can't make a record to the mysql database, data is passed from html and js files to java classes

Tags: java, mysql

I have html and js file and make some kind of chat room, the following java class should store the message to the database, but it doesn't. There is one more java class the retrieves the message from the database and sends back to the user

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ChatStore
  extends HttpServlet
{
  public ChatStore() {}

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    PrintWriter localPrintWriter = paramHttpServletResponse.getWriter();
    try
    {
      paramHttpServletResponse.setContentType("text/html");

      Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection localConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/synergism", "root", "");
      Statement localStatement = localConnection.createStatement();


      String str1 = paramHttpServletRequest.getParameter("uname");
      String str2 = paramHttpServletRequest.getParameter("msg");

      SimpleDateFormat localSimpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
      SimpleDateFormat localSimpleDateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
      Date localDate = new Date();
      String str3 = localSimpleDateFormat1.format(localDate);
      String str4 = localSimpleDateFormat2.format(localDate);

      String str5 = "insert into chat_data values('" + str1 + "','" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "','" + str4 + "';";

      ResultSet localResultSet = localStatement.executeQuery(str5);

      localResultSet.next();
      localConnection.close();
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {
      localException.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Invalid User");
    }
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest paramHttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse paramHttpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    doGet(paramHttpServletRequest, paramHttpServletResponse);
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably not related but why your `doGet` calls itself recursively? Do you want to let someone stop your app with StackOverflow exception?

Comment: Anyway shouldn't `insert` be handled by `executeUpdate` rather than `executeQuery`?

Comment: Also if I you are handling data from user use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to avoid problems with SQL injection.